# How to select a specific field in json data in python

Tags: python, json

I am new to handling data in json file and i am trying to extract specific information ( "expanded_url" in my case). when i am loading the json file as string using json.loads() i cannot select expanded_url data from the list of stings.
i am proving my json data drive link for your reference.

My query: i want to extract only "expanded_url" field mentioned in entity data (it may or may not be empty) from the json file.

json data:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hgnwi74JTECY4cQRp3rG3zX4DX1dGa9A/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you tried any code?

Answer (score 0):

After you  converted your `json` data via `json.loads` you able to manipulate with data via `dictionary` data type.

And a little example how you can to extract `expanded_url` values from your `json` data.

```
def get_by_key(obj):
    return obj["quoted_status"]["extended_tweet"]["extended_entities"]

# `data` means your dictionary object.
media_objects = [get_key(media) for media in data]


for media_obj in media_objects:
    for url in media_obj['media']:
        print(url['expanded_url'])
```

[Useful link](https://realpython.com/python-json/), how to work with `json` in Python